# Fetching a specific GIT revision to my local repository

Tags: git

I'll start from saying that I've using mainly SVN and our project moved recently to Git. I figure out that I don't really understand lot of GIT principles.

My question is practical:

We have a GIT repo hosted on a central place (Beanstalk) and all of us push and pull there.
Now, my local repo got broken, and I need to recreate it. But not the latest revision but a specific one in the past (`bc213be6`,  just an example).

How can I accomplish this?
I would clone the central repository but, as I said above, I need the none latest version.

Thanks

Gidi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloning will get you the full history. *Then* you can choose any revision you want to see in your working tree.

Rather than a reset, I would do a **[`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)** to the right  ('`bc213be6`' for instance, or the right tag if there is one):

```
git clone git://git.myserver.org/myrepo.git
cd myrepo
git checkout <sha1>
```

But if you want to do any modification, create a local branch:

```
git checkout -b myBranch <sha1>
```

If you don't, you would be in a [DETACHED HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714).

Note that you have many way to specify your revision, as explained in [`git rev-parse`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html#_specifying_revisions).

Answer (score 2):

Do a git clone first. Afterwards use a git reset to move HEAD to the commit you want.

Here's the link to the git manual for the reset: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

Comment: It's unlikely that `git reset` is what the questioner wants - [as VonC says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480285/fetching-a-specific-git-revision-to-my-local-repository/5481810#5481810) you can move about between old versions with `git checkout` without changing the position of any branch (as `git reset` would).

Comment: Both appear to accomplish what the questioner wants. From what the user mentioned, he wants a new local repo with a branch with a previous commit from the central repo. That could be accomplished by the reset or the checkout, however with the checkout you need to create a copy of the branch first to avoid the detached HEAD state. With a reset, there's no need of creating another local branch.